# Can not upgrade Sitecore solutions to use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 7.0.0

Tags: nuget

Trying to upgrade Nuget packages for the below listed libraries from `3.1.5` to the latest `Microsoft.Extensions.*.*.7.0.0`.

But as they have been referenced in `Sitecore.Kernel (10.1.0)`. Nuget is still fetching the `3.1.5` version after upgrading them to `7.0.0`.

Can we upgrade to the latest version without upgrading `Sitecore.Kernel` dll to `10.3.0`?

Below package reference page mentioned using `>=3.1.5`
https://sitecore.myget.org/feed/sc-packages/package/nuget/Sitecore.Kernel

```
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.3.1.5
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.3.1.5
Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.Abstractions.3.1.5
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.3.1.5
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.3.1.5
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.3.1.5
```

Comment: removed those references from the project then try. it will work

Answer (score 0):

I tried with my solution, where I am having `Sitecore Kernel 10.1.1` and I was able to update the version of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.3.1.5` to `7.0.0`.

You should first remove those references completely from your project and then try to update them.

Another way you can try is to clear Nuget Cache like below.

- Select `tools->Nuget PackageManager-> Package Manager Settings`
- In the options window that pops up. click `Clear All Nuget Cache(s)`
- Right-click solution and select Restore Nuget Packages.

Hope this will solve your issue.